# Background image in ggplot2 covering the entire canvas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking for a solution that covers both areas as shown in the picture.

[image]

I first tried

```
pic_import <- png::readPNG("background.png")
pic_raster <- grid::rasterGrob(pic_import, interpolate = TRUE)
```

inserted into ggplot:

```
background_image(pic_raster)+
```

or used instead:

```
annotation_custom(pic_raster, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)
```

both ways are not working. I am losing my head over this.

How is it possible to load an image that covers the entire canvas?

thx

Comment: Not working how? Where is `background_image` from?

Comment: i made it myself. 

https://imgur.com/VPlGumP

not working in two ways: either only loaded into the plot.background area
or
not loaded at all with message regarding "rasterGrob"

Comment: `background_image` is a function you're calling—what package is that from?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.2.3/topics/background_image

Comment: not directly an answer to your question, but you may have an easier life and also more flexibility with "generic annotation", e.g. with cowplot https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: @Tjebo I think that could be a fine answer to this question.